# How to separate string in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

In ios how can i separated `NSArray` for example ...my `NSString` is 40 + 30 / 10 * 4 and i want items 40, 30 ,10 and 4 ? it is possible by use of `string componentseparatedbystring` function.
it is possible in this way---> `componentseparatedbystring: @"+,/,*";`

Comment: put a regex for that

Comment: i am just try to make some basic tutorial....i am new in ios

Comment: Did any of the answers below help you?

Comment: yeah .....very helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, you can do it

```
NSString *str = @"40 + 30 / 10 * 4 ";
NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                        [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"/+*"]];        
NSLog(@"%@", arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet`.

More at [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:)